# CXF statistics tracking on the client side?

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf

`CXF` on the server side offers `CounterRepository` with all kind of metrics for `soap` webservices.

If I create a client with cxf, is there any similar metrics tracking?
CounterRepository cannot be used here, as it must be registered with the cxf `SpringBus`, which is not used on plain webservice clients...